# Pass additional parameters to generic implementation

Tags: c#, .net

```
public interface IService<T>
{
    void Do<T>(T entity);
}

...

// The service is assigned by DI container:
public IService<Advert> Service { get; private set; }

...

// Interface method call:
Service.Do(advert);
```

I need to pass additional parameters to method `Do` for this special case. For example:

```
public void Do<Advert>(Advert advert)
{
    ...

    if (additionalParameter)
    {
        // do some special stuff
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there any nice solution without creating special `IAdvertService : IService<Advert>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the signature of the interface method:

```
public interface IService<T>
{
    void Do<T>(T entity, params object[] parameters);
}
```

In this way you don't need to provide parameters, but you can.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. But there are about 80 implementations in solution already.

Comment: But if you need to call it from the interface declaration you have to declare it somewhere...

Comment: You right. I just thought I missed any another good and less time consuming solution. Nevertheless yours is the best for now.

Comment: Maybe a replace all will ease the effort.